# Replacement using regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a very long description containing below icon code of wordpress:

`[glyphicon type="some-icon"] and [dashicon type="another-icon"]`

Now I want replace above old code with below font-awesome code:

`<i class='fa fa-lg fa-some-icon'></i> and <i class='fa fa-lg fa-another-icon'></i>`

I'm new to regex and using below regex to replace `"\\[[^\\[]*\\]"`

Could you help me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not seeing the connection to Java here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex to search for

```
\[(glyph|dash)icon type="([a-z-]*)"\]
```

and the following for the replace

```
<i class='fa fa-lg fa-$2'></i>
```

I used Sublime Text for this

Comment: @ ErShakirAnsari Perhaps some feedback if this isn't working?

Comment: thanks alot.. Can you let me know how to use sublime to find more regex so I dont have to search it again..